How do I get keyboard events in a dialog?
I have written a Python module to produce plots of data. The plots are generated on a dialog because I can use a modal dialog to produce a data plot, then close it to go on with the parent program. It works fine except:
I originally wrote it on a Win10 platform. Control of the plot (close, print, rescale) was initiated by keyboard events. A couple years ago I switched to an M1 MacBook. On the MacOS platform keyboard events do nothing on a dialog. The only key that works is esc. So I placed buttons on the plot to do the control, but having been using keyboard events for the last 30 years I would prefer to keep that method.
The program has evolved from Fortran IV (in the '60s) through Pascal and Delphi 5. I decided to learn Python a couple years ago so I'm still kind of a beginner (age 85). I probably don't use the most efficient Python methods since I basically take the previous code and try to get it to work in Python.
The program is pretty large so I boiled it down to an example. It takes the data, finds the extrema, produces a frame and plots the data within the frame. I stripped out the fancy stuff to keep it simple (grid, tick marks, titles, axis labels, etc.). The plotting module binds keyboard events with wx_EVT_CHAR_HOOK and the bound function prints the keyboard event and performs an appropriate action, but nothing on the keyboard activates it except esc.
How do I get the keyboard to work in a dialog on MacOS (Sonoma 14.4.1)? Using Pycharm.
Program Keyboard.py
import wx
import os
import pyplot20240512 as pp

class ModulePanel(wx.Panel):            #   Feature Selection Panel
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button1=wx.Button(self, label="Quit", pos=(240, 3))
        self.button2=wx.Button(self, label='Act', pos=(120, 3))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClick1,self.button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.StartCode,self.button2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.OnHook)

    def OnHook(self, evt):
        a=evt.GetKeyCode()
        if a==wx.WXK_ESCAPE:exit('Escape')
        elif a==13:self.StartCode(evt)
        elif a==370:self.StartCode(evt)
        elif a==88:self.OnClick1(evt)

        evt.Skip()

    def OnClick1(self,event):    #  Quit button
        quit('Quit')
    def StartCode(self,event):   #  Act button
        pp.G.XMinimum=0
        pp.G.XMaximum=1
        pp.G.YMinimum=0
        pp.G.YMaximum=1

        pp.Frame()
        pp.DrawLine(2,pp.G.red)
        pp.ShowPlot()
        quit('End')

#####################################################################################

app = wx.App(False)
if os.name=='posix':pp.G.OS='MACOS'
elif os.name=='nt':pp.G.OS='WINDOWS'
else: pp.G.OS='?'

frame = wx.Frame(None, pos=(10,50),size=(450,75))

panel = ModulePanel(frame)
pp.G.self=panel
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
exit('End Program')

Module pyplot20240512.py
import wx

class G(object):#Global variables available to modules outside this one as pp.G.variable

#       Colors
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    maroon=(128,0,0)
    olive=(128,128,0)
    orange=(255,128,0)
    yellow = (255, 255, 0)
    gold=(200,200,0)
    lime = (0,255,0)
    green = (0, 165, 0)
    cyan = aqua=(0, 255, 255)
    teal=(0,128,128)
    blue = (0, 0, 255)

    DialogStyle=wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE
    PlotPosition=(10,40)
    ControlPosition=(10,40)

    #       Line styles
    solid=solidline=SolidLine=Solid_Line=wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID
    dottedline=DottedLine=wx.PENSTYLE_DOT
    dashedline=DashedLine=wx.PENSTYLE_SHORT_DASH
    longdashedline=LongDashedLine=wx.PENSTYLE_LONG_DASH
    dotdashline=DotDashLine=wx.PENSTYLE_DOT_DASH

    XMinimum=XMaximum=YMinimum=YMaximum=0
    FrameFlag=True

    PlotElementList=[]
    PlotPanelSize = (1400, 850)     #   8.5x14 paper
    PlotDialogBackgroundColor=(255,255,255)     #   white
    TopMargin = 20
    BottomMargin = 120
    LeftMargin = 80
    RightMargin = 50
    XOrigin = LeftMargin
    YOrigin = PlotPanelSize[1] - BottomMargin

    dc: wx.ClientDC


############################################   Plot is produced on a modal dialog

class PlotDialog(wx.Dialog):    #   Dialog that displays the plotted data
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent,pos=G.PlotPosition,size=G.PlotPanelSize,style=G.DialogStyle)
        #   buttons bound to actions

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK,self.OnHook)


    def OnHook(self, evt):      #   For use in Windows. Does not function in MacOS
        qk=evt.GetKeyCode()
        print('Hook',qk)
        if qk==wx.WXK_ESCAPE:self.CloseButtonAction(evt)
        elif qk==13:self.StartPlot(evt)                 #   return
        elif qk==370:self.StartPlot(evt)                #   return
        elif qk==67:self.CD.ControlCloseAction(evt)     #   c
        elif qk==74:self.CD.ControlCopyAction(evt)      #   j
        elif qk==81:self.CD.ControlExitAction(evt)      #   q
        elif qk==88:self.CD.ControlExitAction(evt)      #   x
        evt.Skip()

    def CloseButtonAction(self, evt):
        print('CloseButtonAction')
        self.EndModal(601)
        self.Destroy()
    def ExitButtonAction(self,evt):
        quit('Exit Button')

#   Paint the plot on the screen

    def on_paint(self, event):
        if not G.ValidPlotRange:exit('Exit With Invalid Plot Range')
        self.SetBackgroundColour(G.PlotDialogBackgroundColor)
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.Clear()
        G.YOrigin=G.PlotPanelSize[1]-G.BottomMargin

        ##########################   Plot Element Actions

        for m in range(0,len(G.PlotElementList)):
        ##################################################################
            if G.PlotElementList[m][0]=='Frame':    #   Draw Frame
                if G.FrameFlag:
                    a = XPos(G.XMinimum)
                    b = YPos(G.YMinimum)
                    c = XPos(G.XMaximum)
                    d = YPos(G.YMaximum)
                    dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(G.black, 1))
                    dc.DrawLine(a, b, c, b)
                    dc.DrawLine(c, b, c, d)
                    dc.DrawLine(c, d, a, d)
                    dc.DrawLine(a, d, a, b)


#################################################

            if G.PlotElementList[m][0]=='PlotLine':
                color=G.PlotElementList[m][3]
                size=G.PlotElementList[m][2]
                PenStyle=G.PlotElementList[m][4]
                id=G.PlotElementList[m][5]
                dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(color, size, PenStyle))
                i=0
                plotpoints=[]
                n=len(G.PlotElementList[m][1])
                if n==0:
                    print('No points in DrawLine', id)
                    break
                for i in range(0,n):
                    a=(G.PlotElementList[m][1][i][0])
                    b=(G.PlotElementList[m][1][i][1])
                    a=XPos(a)
                    b=YPos(b)
                    plotpoints.append((a, b))
                if len(plotpoints) > 1: dc.DrawLines(plotpoints)


###############################   End of paint   #################################

def Limits(V2):     #   Find maxima and minima
    G.XMinimum=V2.X(0,0)
    G.XMaximum=V2.X(0,0)
    G.YMaximum=V2.X(1,0)
    G.YMinimum=V2.X(1,0)
    Limit1(V2)
def Limit1(V2):
    for i in range(0,V2.Count()):
        if (G.XMinimum>V2.X(0,i)): G.XMinimum=V2.X(0,i)
        if (G.XMaximum<V2.X(0,i)): G.XMaximum=V2.X(0,i)
        if (G.YMinimum>V2.X(1,i)): G.YMinimum=V2.X(1,i)
        if (G.YMaximum<V2.X(1,i)): G.YMaximum=V2.X(1,i)

def XPos(x):    #   Find physical location of the x-coordinate on the plot
    z = (x - G.XMinimum) / (G.XMaximum - G.XMinimum)
    q=G.XOrigin + (z * (G.PlotPanelSize[0]-G.RightMargin-G.LeftMargin))
    return (int(q))

def YPos(y):    #   Find physical location of the y-coordinate on the plot
    z = (G.YMinimum-y) / (G.YMaximum - G.YMinimum)
    q=(z * (G.PlotPanelSize[1]-G.TopMargin-G.BottomMargin))+G.YOrigin
    return (int(q))

def Frame(PlotTitle='WindowTitle',JPGTitle='WindowTitle'):# Set up the frame of the plot
    if (G.YMaximum-G.YMinimum)>0 and (G.XMaximum-G.XMinimum)>0:
        G.ValidPlotRange=True
        G.JPGTitle=JPGTitle
        G.PlotElementList.clear()
        G.PlotElementList.append(['Frame', G.XMinimum, G.XMaximum, G.YMinimum, G.YMaximum])
    else: G.ValidPlotRange=False

def ShowPlot(parent=None):
    PD=PlotDialog(parent)
    result=PD.ShowModal()
    return(result)

def DrawLine(size=1,color=G.black,style=G.solid,LineId=''):
    LineList=[]
    LineList.append((0.1,0.1))
    LineList.append((0.2,0.9))
    LineList.append((0.8,0.8))
    LineList.append((0.7,0.1))
    LineList.append((0.1,0.1))
    G.PlotElementList.append(['PlotLine',LineList,size,color,style,LineId])


